# my function in html page is not executing

Tags: javascript, html

Below code is not executing an it is showing "undefined" in the paragraph. could someone please help?

```html
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <button type="button" onclick="getTheNumber();"> Number </button><br>
 <p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
  <script>
   function getTheNumber(){
    var result ;
    var a ;
    var b ;
    a > b ? result = ["A" , a] : ["B" , b] ;
    return result;
   }
   var res = getTheNumber();
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res+"";
  </script>
 </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have var `a` and var `b`, both don't have values. So how can they be compared?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear on what you're trying to achieve. You haven't assigned anything to `result`.

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="getTheNumber();"> Number </button><br>
<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
    <script>
        function getTheNumber(){
            var result ;
            var a ;
            var b ;
            result = a > b ?  ["A" , a] : ["B" , b] ;
            return result;
        }
        var res = getTheNumber();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res+"";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```js
function getTheNumber(a,b){
  console.log(a);
  var result ;
  //var a =4;
  //var b=3 ;
  a > b ? result = ["A" , a] : ["B" , b] ;
  console.log(result);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result+"";
  return result;
 }
function onLoadData(a,b){
 var res = getTheNumber(a,b);
 }
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body onLoad="onLoadData(5,2);">
     <button type="button" onclick="getTheNumber(4,3);return false;">Number </button><br>
     <p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @ShanWave007-Accept the answer and upvote if it works for your problem.It will help for other users.